# Relocate file into subdirectory

Tags: files

How to relocate file1 into subdirectory dir1?

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]. While newbie questions are very welcome, please try and find an answer yourself before posting here. We want to be the _next_ stop after searching, not the first. You might want to read through our [how to ask](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this kind of question could be easily answered with a simple google search.
But here is the solution:

```
mv file1 dir1
```